# PHP nodeValue strips html tags - innerHTML alternative?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm using the following script for a lightweight DOM editor. However, `nodeValue` in my `for` loop is converting my html tags to plain text. What is a PHP alternative to `nodeValue` that would maintain my innerHTML?

```
$page = $_POST['page'];
$json = $_POST['json'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($page);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$entries = $xpath->query('//*[@class="editable"]');
$edits = json_decode($json, true);
$num_edits = count($edits);

for($i=0; $i<$num_edits; $i++) 
{
    $entries->item($i)->nodeValue = $edits[$i]; // nodeValue strips html tags
}

$doc->saveHTMLFile($page);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$edits[$i]` is a string, you need to parse it into a DOM structure and replace the original content with the new structure.

### Update

The code fragment below does an incredible job when using non-XML compliant HTML. (*e.g.* HTML 4/5)

```php
for($i=0; $i<$num_edits; $i++)
{
    $f = new DOMDocument();
    $edit = mb_convert_encoding($edits[$i], 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"); 
    $f->loadHTML($edit);
    $node = $f->documentElement->firstChild;
    $entries->item($i)->nodeValue = "";
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
        $entries->item($i)->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));
    }
}
```

Comment: This feels a bit like cheating since I worked on the original code, but it's a common enough problem that maybe others will benefit from this post. :-)

Comment: Haha - I had posted this question before you answered it in the other post:). Thanks again! Worth noting, using appendXML, I did have to replace some special characters `.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, "&#160;").replace(/<br>/gi, '<br />');` to get it to parse correctly, but all is working well!

Comment: @Josiah: I guess I should have tested more. :-) Anyway, I updated the answer with improved code so you don't have to resort to `replace`. It handles HTML (not XML), even if it contains UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't working with that library in PHP before, but in my other xpath experience I think that nodeValue on anything other than a text node does strip tags. If you're unsure about what's underneath that node, then I think you'll need to recursively descend $entries->item($i)->childNodes if you need to get the markup back.

Or...you may wany textContent instead of nodeValue:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent