# Replace td cell text with new html value

Tags: php, dom, domxpath

I'm trying to replace all td cells text to include link tag. Currently with the code below, the cells are being replaced but when I output the table, it literally just output the html code like so:

```
<a href="sdf" class="link">Some text</a>
```

Instead of a real physical HTML link. How do I actually replace a nodeValue with HTML tags? Thanks.

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument( );
@$DOM->loadHTML( $htmlTable );
$DOMXPath = new DOMXPath( $DOM );

$cellName = $DOMXPath->query('//td[contains(@class,"classA")]');

foreach( $cellName as $text ) {
    $text->nodeValue = '<a href="sdf" class="link">' . htmlspecialchars( trim( $text->nodeValue ) ) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Try `foreach( $cellName as &$text ) {` and tell if it worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857595/php-nodevalue-strips-html-tags-innerhtml-alternative

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work (iterator cannot be use for foreach by refence).

Comment: Not a duplicate issue though. Can't find a workaround with this anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work. In case it helps anyone. In order to change a text node with HTML inside a td value, use the following:

```
$partial = $DOM->createDocumentFragment();
$partial->appendXML('<a href="sdf" class="link">some text</a>');
$text->parentNode->replaceChild($partial, $text );
```